# One to one relation doctrine

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unable to get my entities to work with a one to one relationship.

```js
/**
 * Beacon\Entities\User
 */
class User {
  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $firstName;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $lastName;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $userName;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $password;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $email;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $mobile;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $address1;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $address2;

  /**
   * @var \DateTime
   */
  private $dateCreated;

  /**
   * @var integer
   */
  private $id;



  class UserAccount {
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $ispaid;

    /**
     * @var \Beacon\Entities\User
     */
    private $id;


    <? xml version = "1.0"
    encoding = "utf-8" ?>
      < doctrine - mapping xmlns = "http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns: xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi: schemaLocation = "http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd" >
      < entity name = "Beacon\Entities\UserAccount"
    table = "user_account" >
      < id name = "id"
    association - key = "true" / >
      < field name = "ispaid"
    type = "integer"
    column = "ispaid"
    nullable = "true" >
      < options >
      < option name = "unsigned" / >
      < /options>
    </field >
      < one - to - one field = "id"
    target - entity = "Beacon\Entities\User"
    fetch = "LAZY" >
      < join - columns >
      < join - column name = "id"
    referenced - column - name = "id" / >
      < /join-columns>
    </one - to - one >
      < /entity>
</doctrine - mapping >
```

This is the error I get

> Type: Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException
>
> Message: The given entity of type 'Beacon\Entities\UserAccount'
>   (Beacon\Entities\UserAccount@0000000050a7b33800000000160edb7c) has no
>   identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map.

Where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by doing this

```
 $this->entityManager->persist($user);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $this->entityManager->persist($userAccount);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
```

Due to

```
   $this->entityManager->persist($user);
            $this->entityManager->persist($userAccount);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
```

Throwing the error